# My Windows Service failing to get started after a reboot

Tags: c#, windows-services

I can successfully Start/Stop service Manually but it fails to start on a system restart although startup type is set to `'Automatic'`. On some terminal, when rebooted, service fail to start with error `failed to connect DB`

```
29052019 17:25:27 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - Exception Thrown in getNewSession()

29052019 17:25:27 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - Unable To Open Database Session

29052019 17:25:27 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPoolManager.Pool.CreateNewConnectionIfPossibleImpl(FbConnectionString connectionString)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPoolManager.Pool.GetConnection(FbConnection owner)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at StevensCommon.Database.FluentNHibernateManager.OpenNewSession()
   at StevensCommon.DAOs.StevensDAO.GetNewSession()
```

On development environment whilst debugging I'm not even getting any error. Assuming that on my machine the firebird services does start up before my service, still it fails to start the service on a reboot. And nothing comes up in the log.

I've added some log points within the code and they all gets logged when I Stop/Start the service manually. But nothing shows up in the log when system is rebooted and server never gets started.

Tried adding Firebird Service as a dependencies in the Project/Service Installer, set the `DelayedAutoStart = true`. Whatever solution I read online I've tried it but service is not starting on a reboot.

Following I'm adding starting/entry point snippet of the service.

*Program.cs*

```
static class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("FLAG - Before DAO Call", null);
    // Check to see if we have a licence 
    if (LicenceFileDAO.GetLicence() != null && LicenceManager.IsLicenceActive())
    {
        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("FLAG - Inside DAO Block", null);
        //Run the IS Service
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("FLAG - End of DAO Call", null);
    }
    else
    {
        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("No Valid Licence Found - Either A Licence Has Not Been Activated Or It Has Expired. Please Contact Support", null);
    }
  }
}
```

**MyService.cs**

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    protected static Timer importTimer = null;
    protected static Timer exportTimer = null;
    protected static Timer licenceTimer = null;
    protected static Timer requestTimer = null;
    protected static Timer uploadTimer = null;
    protected static Timer handshakeTimer = null;
    protected static Timer scheduledReportTimer = null;
    protected static Timer alertTimer = null;
    public static Boolean ImportRunning = false;
    public static Boolean ExportRunning = false;
    public static Boolean RequestRunning = false;
    public static Boolean UploadRunning = false;
    public static Boolean HandshakeRunning = false;
    public static Boolean ScheduledReportRunning = false;
    public static Boolean AlertReportRunning = false;
    public static int? zynkWorkflowProcessId = null;

    public MyService()
    {
        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("FLAG - 1", null);

        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeServiceTimers();


        try
        {
            MessengerService.Start();
            TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("Messaging Service Started", null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog(e.Message, e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).BeginInit();
        // 
        // MyService
        // 
        this.ServiceName = "MyService";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).EndInit();

    }

    private void InitializeServiceTimers()
    {
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("Stevens Integration Service"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "Stevens Integration Service", "ServiceLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "Stevens Integration Service";
        eventLog1.Log = "ServiceLog";

        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("FLAG - 2", null);

        importTimer = new Timer(IntegrationServiceSettings.GetImportInterval() * 1000);
        exportTimer = new Timer(IntegrationServiceSettings.GetExportInterval() * 1000);
        licenceTimer = new Timer(86400 * 1000); // Daily
        requestTimer = new Timer(IntegrationServiceSettings.GetRequestInterval() * 1000);
        scheduledReportTimer = new Timer(30000);
        alertTimer = new Timer(20000);

        importTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ImportTimerElapsed);
        exportTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ExportTimerElapsed);
        licenceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(LicenceTimerElapsed);
        requestTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(RequestTimerElapsed);
        scheduledReportTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ScheduledReportTimerElapsed);
        alertTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(AlertTimerElapsed);
        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("FLAG - 3", null);
        StartTimers();
        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("FLAG - 4", null);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Stevens Integration Service Starting...");
        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("FLAG - OnStart() Started", null);

        if (StevensDAO.TestConnection())
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Configure Settings...");
            IntegrationServiceSettings.InitialiseAll();
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Done.");
        }
        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLog("FLAG - OnStart() Finished", null);


        TransactionLogManager.WriteServiceLogInfo("Started");
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Started.");
    }

}
```

**ProjectInstaller** -  That Includes `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller` and `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller`

```
private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller1;
private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller1;
private MyService myService ;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
    this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
    this.myService = new IntegrationService.MyService();

    // serviceProcessInstaller1
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;

    // serviceInstaller1
    this.serviceInstaller1.Description = "My Integration Service";
    this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = "MyService";
    this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "MyService";
    //this.serviceInstaller1.ServicesDependedOn = new string[] { "Firebird Guardian - DefaultInstance", "Firebird Server - DefaultInstance" };
    //this.serviceInstaller1.DelayedAutoStart = true;
    this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

    // myService 
    this.myService.ExitCode = 0;
    this.myService.ServiceName = "MyService";

    // ProjectInstaller
    this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
    this.serviceInstaller1});
}
```

**LogPoints** - On manual Start/Stop I do get following log points, but when I reboot the system nothing comes up

```
30052019 16:19:35 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - FLAG - Before DAO Call
30052019 16:19:35 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - FLAG - Inside DAO Block
30052019 16:19:35 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - FLAG - 1
30052019 16:19:35 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - FLAG - 2
30052019 16:19:35 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - FLAG - 3
30052019 16:19:35 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - FLAG - 4
30052019 16:19:35 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - Messaging Service Started
30052019 16:19:35 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - FLAG - OnStart() Started
30052019 16:19:35 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - Client 1 is now connected!
30052019 16:19:36 ERROR Logs.TransactionLogManager - FLAG - OnStart() Finished
```

Comment: Is there anything in the eventlog?

Comment: Whenever Windows doesn't start a service, it should make a note in the Event Logs. Have you checked the Event Viewer? https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#DiagnoseProblems

Comment: Consider setting the startup type to `Automatic (Delayed Start)`.  Also consider not trying to connect to the database in the `OnStart()` method

Comment: There's nothing in the event log apart from the entries that im writing in code, And these entries only appear in the event log when I'm starting service manually. On a reboot nothing appears in the event log.

Comment: @chadnt I've tried Delayed Start as well, Apparently it worked On & Off for my colleague, but not on my system though. About avoiding DB connection within OnStart, I'll try and let you guys know but I'm wondering If trying to Connect to DB is a problem, then how come none of my log points aren't being logged. It doesn't even log the ones in the `Main()` method within `Program.cs`. Does it mean service is not being started at all or just failing at the very beginning ?